# RPi.GPIO RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

Tags: gpio, python

I ran a python script on a Raspberrypi 4 on Raspbian Bookworm for a ups (uninterruptible power supply) quite a while. Since the latest update of bookworm the script fails. Since the [script](https://github.com/uenz/PiModules/blob/master/code/python/upspico/picofssd/scripts/picofssd) of the ups is somewhat complex i narrowed down the issue to the following code fragment:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

CLOCK_PIN = 27
PULSE_PIN = 22
BOUNCE_TIME = 30

def isr(channel):
    return

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(CLOCK_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(PULSE_PIN, GPIO.OUT, initial=1)
GPIO.add_event_detect(CLOCK_PIN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=isr, bouncetime=BOUNCE_TIME)
time.sleep(30)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

with this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "picofssd.py", line 15, in <module> GPIO.add_event_detect(CLOCK_PIN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=isr, bouncetime=BOUNCE_TIME) RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection`

The code is run in a service as root. Unfortunately i have no idea what can cause the error. Pin 27 should not have another function than gpio and user root should have all access rights.

I found hints that this can be caused when script is run as normal user, but is run as root. Pin has no dual function, so it should also not be a configuration issue.

Any hints what can cause this error?

Comment: What are these pins connected to? How are you using them?

Comment: Its the driver part for this [USV](https://pimodules.com/plus-advanced). It worked for a long time, but stopped with last update ( apt-get upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research i found a solution myself:
It seems that the kernel interface for gpio access changed from library gpio to lgpio.
Switching the python package [rpi-gpio](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/) to  [rpi-lgpio](https://pypi.org/project/rpi-lgpio/) as provider for the RPi.GPIO include solved the issue without any changes in code.

Comment: This is nonsense.  RPi.GPIO never used "the kernel interface" it directly accessed registers.

Comment: @Milliways Maybe the wording is nonsense, but not the message.
Python cannot access the CPU Registers by itself. It relies on a library. The library provided with rpi-gpio stopped working on by bookworm installation with the above mentioned error. Replacing the rpi-gpio library by the rpi-lgpio library did the trick for my installation. May explanation was taken from the description of rpi-lgpio.